# how to get exact value in setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple question...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {            
   setTimeout(function () { alert(i) }, 3000);
}
```

how to alert 5 times with exact value of i.

It gives "5" only 5 times.

I need its result like
0
1
2
3
4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) that keeps the value of the variable constant within the new scope of the immediately invoked function

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {            

   (function(j) {

       setTimeout(function () { alert(j) }, 3000);

   }(i));
}
```

The setTimout is asynchronous, so by the time it executes the loop has long since completed, and the value of `i` has been changed to `5`, so you need to lock it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` alternate to `setTimeout`

Try,

```
var xCnt = 0;
var xInterval = setInterval(function()
                              {
                                xCnt +=1;  
                                alert(xCnt);

                                  if(xCnt == 5)
                                    { 
                                       clearInterval(xInterval); 
                                    }
                              }, 3000);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ny4h/)